# Draw canvas shape

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to draw the following canvas shape. I can't figure out how to make it. I tried to use `lineTo()` but I'm having a hard time positioning those line segments. Moreover it doesn't take a curve shape.

[image]

The `<canvas>` size should be equal to 600x450. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try defining it as a bezier curve?

Comment: I searched it. But I don't know how will it stretch to that shape and have those bends in it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Comment: Can you create a quick fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Using the bezier curve as **Cezar Augusto** demonstrated can be combined with the canvas 2D API's dash settings. `setLineDash(array)` create a dashed line from the array argument. `lineDashOffset` is the offset to where to start the sequence of dashes and gaps

```js
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = canvas.width = innerWidth - 20;
    var h = canvas.height = innerHeight - 20;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    ctx.setLineDash([14, 16]);
    ctx.lineDashOffset = 2;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,h/2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(w / 2, h, w / 2, -h, w, 0);
    ctx.stroke();
```

`setLineDash` takes an array of numbers that represent the number of pixels for the dash then space and so on. If the array length is odd it is repeated to repeat at the start of a dash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method [bezierCurveTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/bezierCurveTo):

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.bezierCurveTo() method of the Canvas 2D API adds a cubic Bézier curve to the path. It requires three points. The first two points are control points and the third one is the end point. The starting point is the last point in the current path, which can be changed using moveTo() before creating the Bézier curve.

Here is a basic example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("opCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth =5;
ctx.strokeStyle ='orange';
ctx.moveTo(150,0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(0,125,300,175,150,300);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id ="opCanvas" width="600" height ="450">
```

Here is a helper tool for doing that: http://www.victoriakirst.com/beziertool/